# Unexpected behaviour by searching for next char

Tags: c++, string

I have a function 'int nextCharType(string s)' which should return an int according to the "type" of the char.

I will sort by a few self-defined types:

- Array (searching for '[')
- Json (searching for '{')
- Quotes (searching for '"')
- Numbers (see isValidNumber)

My functions are the following:

```
int nextCharType(const std::string& s)
{
    char f;
    bool e;
    return nextCharType(s, f, e);
}

int nextCharType(const std::string& s, char& foundChar, bool& error) 
{
    const char errorChar = 0x01;
    const char jsonOpeningBracket = '{';
    const char arrayOpeningBracket = '[';
    const char quoteChar = '"';

    foundChar = errorChar;
    error = false;

    if(s.length() == 0)
    {
        error = true;
        return 0;
    }

    bool foundNumeric = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length() && i != s.npos; i++)
    {
        char c = s.at(i);
        if(c == '\\')
        {
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        if(c == arrayOpeningBracket || c == quoteChar || c == jsonOpeningBracket)
        {
            foundChar = c;
            break;
        }
        else if(((c == '-' || c == '.') && (i + 1 <= s.length() && isValidNumber(s.at(i + 1))))
            || /*number*/ isValidNumber(c)) // check for sign and decimal char
        {

            foundChar = c;
            foundNumeric = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(foundChar == errorChar)
    {
        error = true;
        return 0;
    }

    if(foundNumeric)
        return 4;

    switch(foundChar)
    {
        case jsonOpeningBracket:
            return 1;
            break;
        case arrayOpeningBracket:
            return 2;
            break;
        case quoteChar:
            return 3;
            break;
        default:
            error = true;
            return 0;
            break;
    }
}

bool isValidNumber(const string& num)
{
    if(num.empty())
        return false;
    if(countChar(num, '.') > 1) // countChar will simply count the given char in the string and return an int
        return false;
    if(countChar(num, '-') > 1)
        return false;

    std::size_t pos = 0;
    if(num.at(0) == '-')
    {
        pos = 1;
    }

    string internalNum = num;
    if(internalNum.find_first_not_of("0123456789.", pos) == internalNum.npos)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Now my Problem:

I have some unittests and one of them is failing and I do not know why.
I call

```
string s = "  dasdas  {";
// should return 1 for the curly bracket.
int ret = nextCharType(s);
// ret is 4 - numeric value.
// foundChar is ' ' - a space.
```

What confuse me is that I test isValidNumber with some unit tests and if i test it, it works like expected.

```
bool valid = isValidNumber(" "); // space - not valid
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: `&& i != s.npos` - why? an `int` can never be any close to max value of `size_t`

Comment: `nextCharType(s);` would case compile error. you don't have such function.

Comment: nextCharType(s) would not crash because I have some alias functions which will provide the needed parameters and just do not return them. I will update my question

Comment: @Fureeish Previously I used std::site_t i in the for loop - while i debugged i changed it because of no real reason.

Comment: you need to provide [mcve]. your code now obviously not compile.

Comment: how is  jsonOpeningBracket defined? and others ?

Comment: @appleapple At the top of the code block I added the function which will make the example compile.

Comment: @Angen They are const char arrayOpeningBracket = '['; and so on. I will add them too.

Comment: you say isValidNumber(" ") works fine, have you tried isValidNumber(' ') ? " " and  ' ' are total different things

Comment: I just tried with " " not with ' '. Thanks for the hint. I will test them now with that.

Comment: @HenrikViebrock no, it would not. have you tried to compile it before post? you ask for unit test (logic) error when your code does not compile, I don't think you would get good answer.

Comment: @Angen Your Hint is helpful. The test for isValidNumber(' ') failed. Now I have to find out why. Can you help me with that too?

Comment: There's an overload of `isValidNumber` that you're using but haven't posted.

Comment: probably you are passing char and expecting string as parameter, consider that s.at(i) returns only one character '1', '2', '.' and never "1.0" or something like that

Comment: @molbdnilo Correct. I found an overload isValidNumber(double) in a file which should not be part of the project. I removed it and now I needed an alias function isValidNumber(char) which calls isValidNumber(string(&c)) and now everything works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: @HenrikViebrock `string(&c)` is more than likely undefined. Just say `std::isdigit(c)`.

Comment: good Point @molbdnilo

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that there existed an overloaded function isValidNumber(double) which was called, instead of isValidNumber(string), when a char was given.
After removing it a adding a new function:

```
bool isValidNumber(char c) {
    return std::isdigit(c);
}
```

the problem is solved.

Answer (score -4):

- 'arrayOpeningBracket' was not declared in this scope !
- 'quoteChar' was not declared in this scope !
- 'jsonOpeningBracket' was not declared in this scope!

there have many of variable not declared! so Firstly declared that

"else if(((c == '-' || c == '.') && (i + 1 <= s.length() && isValidNumber(s.at(i + 1))))" there have missing ')' one bracket !!

Comment: bracket is on the next line, variables are defined elsewhere